# The watch command does not work with a command using a pipe

Tags: bash, watch, ls, wc

Very simple/quick question, why this command does not work?

```
watch ls *.log | wc -l
```

or

```
watch -d ls *.log | wc -l
```

I'm attempting to *watch* an update of the total amount of files in the current directory.

Comment: That command does not make sense. Watch is refresingh the screen periodically, forever. In the case where the command would work, the execution will never finish. The expected `wc -l` output would be `infinite`.

Comment: @Poshi, this works `watch -d ls *.log` and highlight the differences between successive updates. But why it is not possible to pipe it to the `wc` command?

Comment: Why do you say it does not work? Which is the error message?

Comment: Do you want to watch the command `ls *.log | wc -l` or do you want to watch the command `ls *.log` and count the lines in the watch command using `wc -l`?

Comment: @kvantour I want to count the number of files in a particular directory  between successive updates.  This solution `watch "ls | wc -l"` works and provided by 'Bayou' .

Comment: But he explicitly stated in the title that he was piping the output of watch (and ls). And the he asks in the comment why he cannot pipe the highlighted output of watch to the wc... The accepted answer is something completely different from this :'(

Comment: Related on [unix.se]: _[How to use watch command with a piped chain of commands/programs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318859)_

Comment: Why was this question closed? I found it a genuinely useful question and answer. Perhaps because it's a duplicate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pipe a command and watch that, add quotes around it as such:

```sh
watch "ls | wc -l"
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though the problem here is clearly the quoting, you should never parse the command `ls`. The canonical way to count the number of files in a directory is:

```
find /path/to/dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "c" | wc -c
```

This avoids problems with funny names which might contain newline characters.

The solution to the OP would then read:

```
watch 'find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "c" | wc -c'
```

Comment: Thanks and agree with you about the special chars in the filename. However, the `maxdepth=1` should be `maxdepth 1`.